# The replicate function implemented by list comprehension

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and I have tried to implement the `replicate` function  on my own and below is result of my work:

```
replicate' :: Enum a => a -> b -> [b]
replicate' a b = [b | _ <- [1..a]]
```

but during loading script into ghci I got msg:

```
proginhaskell.hs:152:29:
Could not deduce (Num a) arising from the literal `1'
from the context (Enum a)
  bound by the type signature for
             replicate' :: Enum a => a -> b -> [b]
  at proginhaskell.hs:152:1-34
Possible fix:
  add (Num a) to the context of
    the type signature for replicate' :: Enum a => a -> b -> [b]
In the expression: 1
In the expression: [1 .. a]
In a stmt of a list comprehension: _ <- [1 .. a]
```

I would like to ask how to repair this problem. Is it correct way to implement replicate function ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the list expression `[1..a]` that means that we have to be able to treat `1` as the same type as `a`. The type of `1` is

```
1 :: Num a => a -- Numbers are actually polymorphic!
```

So GHC is complaining that you haven't said that `a` is a `Num` instance. So you can just add `Num` to your constraints on `a`.

```
replicate' :: (Enum a, Num a) => a -> b -> [b]
replicate' a b = [b | _ <- [1..a]]
```

As for how good this code is, I'd probably write it with `take`, but both are fine implementations. If you're curious how it's actually implemented (though with a more restrictive `replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`)

```
replicate n x = take n (repeat x)
```

Comment: "As for how good this code is, I'd probably write it with explicit recursion, to avoid generating a useless list, but both are fine implementations." - I believe GHC is able to optimize this case, and get rid of the list generated by `[1..a]`. See [Short cut fusion](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Short_cut_fusion).

Comment: @PedroRodrigues I got curious and analysed the core, it seems both are compiled to the same code, and in the end I prefer preludes `take`. I've edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

From this snippet of code `[1..a]` the compiler inferes that `a` should have the same of type as `1`. Since `1` is a `Num`, it follows that `a` should be of type `Num`. So instead of `Enum a` you should have `(Enum a, Num a)` as your context.